# global variable in appdelegate swift4

Tags: ios, swift

I have the variable I created in appDelegate. how do I use this variable in ViewController. I've tried a few methods, but. I always got an error. my code is as follows. I am swifte new Please help?

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

// refreshedToken is variable. I use it in viewcontroller.
        if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

       }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
   super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    let purl = URL(string: "")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: purl)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let postString = "ajax=token&"+"token="+refreshedToken// Use of unresolved identifier 'refreshedToken'

    print("postString: \(postString)")
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    }
    task.resume()






}
```

how do I use the refreshedToken in ViewController ?

Comment: What data type will there for refreshedToken ?

Comment: @PaulMarshal string

Comment: Create a Model singleton on App Delegate and save the refresh Token on on that model and access that singleton from your View Controller

Comment: @Md.Sulayman how will i do this? I am constantly getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand in what scope you declare a variable and how it is visible outside that scope. Now your variable is only visible inside that func, to make it visible to your view controller it needs to be a class property in AppDelegate.

So define a property like (somewhat simplified code here)

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
   var refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
   ...

}
```

And then in you can access it in your view controller

```
let token = appDelegate.refreshedToken
```

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
     

        if  var refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }}

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController {
   
    let token = AppDelegate.refreshedToken// Type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'refreshedToken'. Why ? Where is my mistake?
    ......

Comment: You don't declare refreshedToken in the func but as a property on the class.

Comment: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

var refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token().....                   class ViewController: UIViewController {
   
    let token = AppDelegate.refreshedToken
nstance member 'refreshedToken' cannot be used on type 'AppDelegate'      I don't understand sorry.

Comment: Check the solution, i have posted it

Answer (score 0):

Just create your refreshedToken globally in appdelegate class and update code as follows:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var refreshedToken : String?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // refreshedToken is variable. I use it in viewcontroller.
        if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            self.refreshedToken = token
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        }
    }
}
```

From above code, refreshedToken available if `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method called otherwise it will be nil.

If you want it global available in application without dependent on any method write following code just after AppDelegate class implementation.

```
let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the refresh token in UserDefaults

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

// refreshedToken is variable. I use it in viewcontroller.
        if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(refreshedToken, forKey: "preferenceName")

       }
}
```

**and Later can retrieve the value in ViewController using**

```
let postString = "ajax=token&"+"token="+  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with Singleton Model Object which will hold your data and has global access of data from anywhere of your project.

First create a new Model File that will have code written below:

```
class SingletonDataModel: NSObject {

    var token:String?

    static let sharedInstance = SingletonDataModel()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Secondly save data on this upper model from `ApppDelegate` class like below:

```
var refreshedToken : String?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // refreshedToken is variable. I use it in viewcontroller.
    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        refreshedToken = token
        SingletonDataModel.sharedInstance.token = token
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    }
}
```

Now your data model singleton is initialized and token value is stored on that object

Finally access that value from your `viewDidLoad` method of the `ViewController` `Class` filelike below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let token = SingletonDataModel.sharedInstance.token

    //Do your work


}
```

if `token` is `nil` , this mean your `AppDelegate` -> `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method is not called before the initialization of your `ViewController`. You must ensure that your `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called before the initialization of your `ViewController` . Otherwise you have to handle this in different way

Comment: This looks like a lot of extra work for very little gain. And why do you inherit from NSObject?

Comment: Not needed. Auto generated by XCode. And i know it's extra work. The question did not mentioned the full flow/scenario and i just wanted to help :)

Comment: Thank you so much ,  I have a question. let postString = "ajax=token&"+"token="+token!    Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value   is there an error with this global variable?

Comment: It’s a bad habit to inherit when you don’t need to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was a mistake. I usually don't inherit unless I need.  Thanks for the comment @Joakim

Comment: When do you call this method named didRegisterForRemoteNotification?? I think your view controller is created before setting the value on token. I suggest you to remove the code below the super.viewDidLoad() method and wrap them on a function and call the method when you finished register for remote notification